# mvn package failes even with -DfailIfNoTests=false

Tags: maven, testing, jar, packaging

I have a maven build which I would like to execute the jar creation for, but `mvn package` fails due to unit test failures.

I'd like to still build the jar in spite of the fact that some tests fail, I tried

```
mvn package -Dtest=false -DfailIFNoTests=false
```

But that fails.

`mvn jar:jar`  seems to work, but I'd rather use the more idiomatic `mvn package` approach.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.119s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 11 12:07:16 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/234M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project glusterfs: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) plugin controls test running and failure reporting.

`mvn package -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`

should compile and run your tests, but not fail the whole build if some of the tests fail.  (I've never used this, going on reading docs only.)

Answer (score 0):

You can skip running unit tests with the following:

> -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Answer (score 0):

We use the `-DskipTests` flag in our pipeline. One setup builds (without tests) and the next step runs the tests, this way we easily see in the pipeline if it failed due to build or tests.